# How can I loop an array starting at 0 while the key of the array is not starting at 0 in php?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, I have an array like this:

```
$array={'199' => 'a','200' => 'c', '23' => 'd'}
```

I would like to use for each loop to loop through all the elements. However, the key is not started at 0. One of the solutions I figured out is to use $i++ to represent the index of each element. Are there any other solutions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(array_values($array) as $key => $value) {
    echo "key: $key, value: $value\n";
}
```

That's how you iterate over an associative array

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But In this case, the first key will be 199 instead of 0 in this example.

Comment: Isnt that the expected behavior? What exactly do you want?

Comment: You don't have an array key with the value 0. Please clarify.

Comment: I would like to have the key starts from 0 instead, which is the order of the elements.

Comment: Then your array needs to be `$array={'0' => 'a','200' = > 'c', '23' => 'd'}`

Comment: No, I mean how can I extract the order of each element when looping through them.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. To reset the indexes of the array, just use array_values()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo 'order: '.$i.', key: '.$key.', value: '.$value.'<br>';
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: He wants to know the order of the array items, starting with 0. As far as I can tell, this answers his question.

Comment: I agree this also answers the question as `$i` would have the same value as `$key` from my answer. If OP wanted to keep both the key and the value of his associative array and have a counter starting at 0 for each array element, this would have been the accepted answer